# How do I prevent writing of invalid JSON when the nodejs service is stopped or crashes?

Tags: node.js, json, systemd

#### The Usecase

I have a NodeJS service (also is a sysemd service) where I write out the internal state as .json

This is for the purpose to have this state persist through crashes or service restarts.

#### The Problem...

Appearently when the service is stopped, restarted or crashing exactly at then time when the file is being written - it would add inconsistent `}` and numbers resulting in an invalid JSON to be parsed when reading the file after restart.

#### The Question

How could I assure that it would manage to write it cleanly at least for the cases where the service is restarted via systemd?

Comment: One rather undesirable solution would be to write 2 files for the same state where I would assume that only one could become corrupted then.